# PHP form process error

Tags: php, forms, email

I've gotten help from this site lots of times, but this is the first time I need to post my own specifics.

I have a PHP registration form, and I'm sure it's a minor problem, but I don't know *exactly* what I need to fix. So, I'd appreciate somebody glancing over it.

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
$email_to = "c@d.com";
$email_subject = "Form Submitted";
$email_from = "c@d.com";

function died($error) {
    // your error code can go here
    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
    die();
}

// validation expected data exists
if(!isset($_POST['Agency']) ||
    !isset($_POST['AgencyPhone'])) {
    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');      
}

$Agency = $_POST['Agency']; // required
$AgencyPhone = $_POST['AgencyPhone']; // required
$contact = $_POST['contact']; // not required
...this goes on for quite some time...
$Zip = $_POST['Zip']; // not required

$error_message = "";
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$Agency)) {
$error_message .= 'The Agency Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($AgencyPhone) < 2) {
$error_message .= 'The Agency Phone you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
$email_message = "You received a message from your site!\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message="
Class: ".$contact."
Dates: ".$Dates." through ".$through."
Location: ".$Location."
Fee: ".$Fee.", ".$Rate."

Students:
1: ".$Last1.", ".$First1.", ".$Email1.", ".$Phone1."\n;
2: ".$Last2.", ".$First2.", ".$Email2.", ".$Phone2."\n;
3: ".$Last3.", ".$First3.", ".$Email3.", ".$Phone3."\n;
4: ".$Last4.", ".$First4.", ".$Email4.", ".$Phone4."\n;
5: ".$Last5.", ".$First5.", ".$Email5.", ".$Phone5."\n;

Agency: ".$Agency.";
Mailing: ".$Mailing.";
City: ".$City.";
Zip: ".$Zip.";
Agency Phone: ".$AgencyPhone.";
"

// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 
?>

...Then, I have the content of the process page...


<!-- Do not change anything below this line -->

<?php 
}    
?>
```

So, the error is in this line.

```
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
```

Or, *an* error is, anyway. What's missing, or what do I need to add? Thanks for whatever help you can give. I really appreciate it.

My form is:

```
<form action="Rprocess.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="body">
  <p><span class="title">Enter Class Date, Location and Fee</span><br />
        <span class="style3">for which you are registering</span>:</p>
      <p align="left" class="style1">Dates:
        <input type="text" name="Dates" size="15" id="Dates" />
      through
      <input type="text" name="through" size="15" id="through" />
      </p>
      <p align="left" class="style1">Location: 
        <input type="text" name="Location" size="48" id="Location" />
      </p>
      <div class="field form-inline radio2">
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2">
          <tr>
          <td width="509"><span class="style1">Registration Fee:
              <input name="Fee" type="text" id="Fee" value="$" size="15" />
per student</span></td>
          </tr>
      </table>
      <p class="style1">Please fill in fields below.<br />
        <span class="style3">(Confirmation e-mail will be forwarded to attendee and Registrant Agency upon receipt.)</span></p>
      <p><span class="title">Student Information</span>:</p>
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2">
        <tr>
          <td width="25%"><span class="style1">Last</span></td>
          <td><span class="style1">First</span></td>
          <td width="25%"><span class="style1">E-mail</span></td>
          <td width="25%"><span class="style1">Phone</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="25%"><span class="style1">
            <input type="text" name="Last1" size="15" id="Last1" />
          </span></td>
          <td><span class="style1">
            <input type="text" name="First1" size="15" id="First1" />
          </span></td>
          <td width="25%"><span class="style1">
            <input type="text" name="Email1" size="15" id="Email1" />
          </span></td>
          <td width="25%"><span class="style1">
            <input type="text" name="Phone1" size="15" id="Phone1" />
          </span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><span class="style1">
            <input type="text" name="Last2" size="15" id="Last2" />
          </span></td>
          <td><span class="style1">
            <input type="text" name="First2" size="15" id="First2" />
          </span></td>
          <td><span class="style1">
            <input type="text" name="Email2" size="15" id="Email2" />
          </span></td>
          <td><span class="style1">
            <input type="text" name="Phone2" size="15" id="Phone2" />
          </span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><span class="style1">
            <input type="text" name="Last3" size="15" id="Last3" />
          </span></td>
          <td><span class="style1">
            <input type="text" name="First3" size="15" id="First3" />
          </span></td>
          <td><span class="style1">
            <input type="text" name="Email3" size="15" id="Email3" />
          </span></td>
          <td><span class="style1">
            <input type="text" name="Phone3" size="15" id="Phone3" />
          </span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><span class="style1">
            <input type="text" name="Last4" size="15" id="Last4" />
          </span></td>
          <td><span class="style1">
            <input type="text" name="First4" size="15" id="First4" />
          </span></td>
          <td><span class="style1">
            <input type="text" name="Email4" size="15" id="Email4" />
          </span></td>
          <td><span class="style1">
            <input type="text" name="Phone4" size="15" id="Phone4" />
          </span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><span class="style1">
            <input type="text" name="Last5" size="15" id="Last5" />
          </span></td>
          <td><span class="style1">
            <input type="text" name="First5" size="15" id="First5" />
          </span></td>
          <td><span class="style1">
            <input type="text" name="Email5" size="15" id="Email5" />
          </span></td>
          <td><span class="style1">
            <input type="text" name="Phone5" size="15" id="Phone5" />
          </span></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <p><span class="title">Registrant Agency Information</span>:</p>
      <p align="left" class="style1"><strong>Agency Name*</strong>:
        <input type="text" name="Agency" size="48" id="Agency" />
      </p>
      <p align="left" class="style1">Mailing Address:
        <input type="text" name="Mailing" size="48" id="Mailing" />
      </p>
      <p align="left" class="style1">City:
        <input type="text" name="City" size="48" id="City" /> 
        Zip: 
        <input type="text" name="Zip" size="15" id="Zip" />
      </p>
      <p align="left" class="style1"><strong>Phone*</strong>:
        <input name="AgencyPhone" type="text" id="AgencyPhone" size="48" />
      </p>
       <p align="center"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
      </form>
```

I also had a set of radio buttons (named Rate) and check boxes (named Fee) that I deleted out of this. One problem at a time...

Comment: It looks like you're missing a semi-colon on the previous line. It would really, really help if you posted what the actual error message you're getting is, though.

Comment: Try this `$headers = 'From: $email_from' . "\r\n" .     'Reply-To: $email_from' . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();`

Comment: Sure! "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /Rprocess.php on line 91 "

Comment: @cnh Or `$headers = 'From: ' . $email_from . "\r\n" .  'Reply-To: ' . $email_from . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();`

Comment: And then just delete the next two lines? What about the line,
    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);

Comment: @cnh Also try changing this `$email_to = "c@d.com";` **and** `$email_from = "c@d.com";` **to** `$email_to = 'c@d.com';` **and** `$email_from = 'c@d.com';`

Comment: @cnh No, keep those, you need them => `@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);`

Comment: Yeah, I'm still getting that same error, either way.

Comment: @cnh Is this line actually part of your (executing) code => `...Then, I have the content of the process page...` If so, delete it then try it again.

Comment: @cnh Try to also change `$email_subject = "Form Submitted";` **to** `$email_subject = 'Form Submitted';` - sometimes using double quotes produces an error in conjunction with headers. It's happened before.

Comment: @cnh - you need to put a semi colon after the line `Agency Phone: ".$AgencyPhone.";
"`

Comment: No, I just have HTML for the process page there. I have have a smaller contact form that I used as a template and it works, but when I put in all the fields I need for this larger registration form, it won't work.

Comment: @cnh Try using `$email_message='` and closing it with `Agency Phone: ".$AgencyPhone."; '` using opening and closing single quotes instead of double quotes.

Comment: @andrewsi, when I add another semicolon there, after changing these to single quotes, it won't give an error or anything, just a blank white page.

Comment: @cnh Don't add another ending semi-colon, you already have it closing. Least that's what I think. Btw, did you see my [**previous comment**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18112183/php-form-process-error#comment26518401_18112183) ?

Comment: @cnh - I'm finding your code hard to read; you're opening a string with `$email_message="`, and the code you've posted does not have a semi-colon when you close that string again, 20 lines later. I find spreading one string over multiple lines makes code harder to maintain - I'm a big fan of doing more work now if it makes my life easier in future.

Comment: @Fred, Yes, it's just the HTML for the process page there. Now I have single quotes for the headers and have tried both of your options for that line, and still get the same error.

Comment: @cnh Try using `if(isset($_POST['email_from']))` instead of your `['email']` doesn't look like it's defined anywhere else. That may very well be the problem. Yet if your input form field is in fact called `email`, then you will need to define it. That's all I can come up with now, without having your actual form to test with.

Comment: @Fred I'll try it, but don't know where to put it. :-)

Comment: @cnh Just replace the line at the top that reads as `if(isset($_POST['email'])){` with `if(isset($_POST['email_from'])){`

Comment: I added that line above `if(!isset($_POST['Agency']) ||` and now I'm getting a message, "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING" for the same headers line.

Comment: @cnh I forgot to include the curly braces above. Reload to see it, in case.

Comment: Oh, I see. I did, and still have the second error. Is the problem getting better or worse? :-) I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @cnh No, get rid of that, it doesn't belong "there". It belong underneath your first line `<?php`. Which should read `<?php if(isset($_POST['email_from'])) { // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED`

Comment: I changed it, and am now getting "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING", same line.

Comment: @cnh Give me a few minutes, it's the headers. Testing without a form.

Comment: @cnh Ok, from what I can tell is this. There is nothing wrong with the syntax for your headers, what is causing the problem is that you have two `$email_message = "...` and it's causing havoc. I was able to get something out of it, but can't fully test without a copy of your form code.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Do you want me to email you?

Comment: @cnh Try to change this `Agency Phone: ".$AgencyPhone.";"` **to** `Agency Phone: ".$AgencyPhone."";` seems like the semi-colon was at the wrong place, or added one. I got it to work but can't tell for sure if it will email without the form.

Comment: @cnh Ok, success! I changed the `if` conditions and received the email. Will post as an answer and give it a try.

Comment: @Fred That didn't fix it, either.

Comment: @cnh See my answer below. Keep me posted.

Comment: @cnh I edited my answer. See the comments inside my code. And, you still with me here? LOL

Comment: @cnh In regards to `radio` buttons and/or `checkbox` options. You can now add them but remember to try and NOT have any spaces between words and use underscores. I.e.: `<input type="radio" value="Radio_NO" name="radios">No<input type="radio" value="Radio_YES" checked name="radios">Yes`

Comment: @andrewsi **Just a quick note:** It was in fact a misplaced semi-colon in `Agency Phone: ".$AgencyPhone.";"` which should have read as `Agency Phone: ".$AgencyPhone."";` and should have been on the outside instead of being "sandwiched", *as it were*. The OP had it as `";"` when it needed to be `"";` - plus there were other errors but I fixed them. I added a `foreach` in regards to the `POST` variables/form fields, which will eleviate the work to define each variable/form field. This one was a doozy! lol cheers

Comment: @Fred - you are a patient, patient man!

Comment: @andrewsi Yes I am. Plus to prove I'm patient, I grow "cactus" Really. One has to be! lol.

Comment: @andrewsi To add, I first remember when I discovered forms back in the mid 90s, and never lost my love/fascination for them. So if I can help someone else in the process/learning, great.

Comment: @andrewsi Btw, are you actually in Ottawa, ON? You have a .co.uk Web address.

Comment: @Fred - yep, Ottawa it is; I'm British but I've been in Canada for a little over two years now.

Comment: @andrewsi Cool! (neighbour) ;-) so you like it here? Been to the RIBFEST? yummy

Comment: @Fred - alas, I'm not allowed to eat ribs in public. It's.... not a pretty sight. I love Ottawa.

Comment: @andrewsi Like 'em that much eh? lol same here! I go there every year, and I make sure always pack an extra 10 or 20 napkins.

Comment: @Fred - you'll have to join us at the Ottawa Geek Social Club some time (it's on meetup.com)

Comment: @andrewsi Thanks Andrew, I do believe I'm already on `meetup.com`, and will see if my account is still active.

Comment: @andrewsi Yep, still have the account. Just had to reset everything. Will keep an eye out for the next one. Is there a way to send each other messages from within meetup.com?

Comment: @Fred - you can send a public message to someone in the same group, I believe; and there's an option to email someone, too.

Comment: @andrewsi Ok, I see it now. And there's one tonight, can't make it. Any chance to know how I can find you on there?

Comment: @andrewsi Scratch that, I think I found you lol Glasses?

Comment: @Fred - Maaaaaaaaaybe ;)

Comment: @andrewsi LOL! ok, I'll see if I can send you something now. Clue: My photo....he's from your country of origin ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ## NEW VERSION (edit)

#### Previous form processor is located under this one.

There were a few errors.

It was in fact a misplaced semi-colon in `Agency Phone: ".$AgencyPhone.";"` which should have read as `Agency Phone: ".$AgencyPhone."";` and should have been on the outside instead of being "sandwiched", as it were. The OP had it as `";"` when it needed to be `"";`

Another error was that the `email` variable was not defined. Since the form did not contain an input field called "email", replaced `if(isset($_POST['email'])) {` with `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {`

A `foreach` was also added to eleviate the work to define each of the form's fields/variables.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
$email_to = "c@d.com";
$email_subject = "Form Submitted";
$email_from = "c@d.com";

function died($error) {
    // your error code can go here
    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
    die();
}

// validation expected data exists
if(!isset($_POST['Agency']) ||
    !isset($_POST['AgencyPhone'])) {
    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');      
}

$Agency = $_POST['Agency']; // required
$AgencyPhone = $_POST['AgencyPhone']; // required
$contact = $_POST['contact']; // not required

$Zip = $_POST['Zip']; // not required

$error_message = "";
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$Agency)) {
$error_message .= 'The Agency Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($AgencyPhone) < 2) {
$error_message .= 'The Agency Phone you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

// This is where all the MAGIC happens
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value) {
    $email_message.=$key.": " . $value . "\n";
}

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";

$headers .= 'From: ' . $email_from . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email_from . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

if(mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers))
{
  echo "Mail Sent Successfully";


}else{
  echo "Mail Not Sent";
}

?>

<?php 
}
?>
```

---

---

> ## OLD VERSION

Give this a try:

```
<?php
    // You may have to use "email" or "email_from" - comment one out.
    // if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    if(isset($_POST['email_from'])) {

// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
$email_to = "c@d.com";
$email_subject = "Form Submitted";
$email_from = "c@d.com";

function died($error) {
    // your error code can go here
    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
    die();
}

// validation expected data exists
if(!isset($_POST['Agency']) ||
    !isset($_POST['AgencyPhone'])) {
    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');      
}

$Agency = $_POST['Agency']; // required
$AgencyPhone = $_POST['AgencyPhone']; // required
$contact = $_POST['contact']; // not required

$Zip = $_POST['Zip']; // not required

$error_message = "";
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$Agency)) {
$error_message .= 'The Agency Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($AgencyPhone) < 2) {
$error_message .= 'The Agency Phone you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
// $email_message = "You received a message from your site!\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message="
Class: ".$contact."
Dates: ".$Dates." through ".$through."
Location: ".$Location."
Fee: ".$Fee.", ".$Rate."

Students:
1: ".$Last1.", ".$First1.", ".$Email1.", ".$Phone1."\n;
2: ".$Last2.", ".$First2.", ".$Email2.", ".$Phone2."\n;
3: ".$Last3.", ".$First3.", ".$Email3.", ".$Phone3."\n;
4: ".$Last4.", ".$First4.", ".$Email4.", ".$Phone4."\n;
5: ".$Last5.", ".$First5.", ".$Email5.", ".$Phone5."\n;

Agency: ".$Agency.";
Mailing: ".$Mailing.";
City: ".$City.";
Zip: ".$Zip.";
Agency Phone: ".$AgencyPhone."
";

// create email headers
// $headers = 'From: $email_from' ."\r\n" . 'Reply-To: $email_from' . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";

// You can comment out the line below if sending an HTML based message
//$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

$headers .= 'From: ' . $email_from . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email_from . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

// Previous mail function with @ symbol
// @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 
  // mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 

if(mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers))
{
echo "Mail Sent Successfully";

}else{
echo "Mail Not Sent";
}

?>



<?php 
}    
?>
```

Comment: It's giving me a white page, without any notice of an error, but isn't sending the form. Should I post that code, too? I'm sorry to put you through trouble, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @cnh It sent me an email when I put in my email address, I don't know why you didn't receive it. Did you change both `c@d.com` to your own Email address? And I did get results back, but nothing from the form inputs, because I don't have the form to go with it. And it's ok, I don't mind... today lol! no work to do today.

Comment: @cnh You should post your **form** in your question, that way I can test it fully.

Comment: @cnh Here's what I got in my email `Class: Dates: through Location: Fee: , Students: 1: , , , ; 2: , , , ; 3: , , , ; 4: , , , ; 5: , , , ; Agency: ; Mailing: ; City: ; Zip: ; Agency Phone:` there is no extra data because I don't have the form to fill the info into.

Comment: I posted the form in the original post. :-)

Comment: @cnh Yes I saw that, but first re-copy my new code, I added a function that if the mail was successfully sent, will show a message. Now, you didn't answer my question earlier. It being, did you change both instances of `c@d.com` that you have in the form to your own? Because if not, the emails are going there `c@d.com`

Comment: @cnh Ok. Now another reason why it gave you trouble is because `if(isset($_POST['email'])) {` is not defined anywhere in your form. There must be an input field called `<input type="text" name="email_from" size="15" id="Email_main" />` for example. If don't want to add one, then use `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {` instead of `if(!isset($_POST['email_from'])) {`. However, your `submit` button hasn't been given a name, so you'll need to change this `input type="submit" value="Submit" />` **to** `input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />` in your form.

Comment: Ok, now the mail sent. Which is AWESOME. Now I just have a couple of minor errors with names that I guess aren't the same on the form and the process page. I can go over those. Thanks so much, @Fred! You're the best! :-)

Comment: @cnh You're welcome. In your form, there are fields called `Last1` `Last2` etc. Those won't show in email because they are not defined in your processing PHP. In order to do that, this `$Last1 = $_POST['Last1'];` must be declared where your `$email_subject = 'Form Submitted';` is, but there's a way around that in order to avoid having to put in each and every one of those variables. I'm looking into it now, and hopefully will have an answer; hopefully.

Comment: @cnh I've got good news for you, however there's a bit of work to be done on your part and that will be to change each name ID's to their respective purpose. For instance: `<input type="text" name="Last1" size="15" id="Last1" />` would need to be renamed to `<input type="text" name="Last_name_1" size="15" id="Last_name_1" />` etc. The method I came up will take each POST input and include them automatically in the email. I will Edit my answer to add another version, while keeping the old one intact.

Comment: @cnh **New version** is up and remember to change `<input type="submit" value="Submit" />` **to** `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />` in your **form** and clear your browser cache etc. just in case.

Comment: @cnh And if you could mark this question as answered by checking the **checkmark** over to the left, that will mark it as being resolved and not stay in the "unanswered" section of SO. Keep me posted.